# Angular 9 - Karma - spyon on window.scroll polymorphism

Tags: typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular9

I have a problem in Angular 9 ( in angular 7, i haven't this problem ).
In my test, i have this :

> const spyWindoScroll = spyOn(window, 'scroll');
>
> ...
>
> expect(spyWindoScroll).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ behavior: 'smooth',
> left: 0, top: -50 });

But when i launch ng test, i have this error :

> error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

I don't understand because window.scroll have two definition for method scroll

> ```
> interface Window extends ...
> ...
> scroll(options?: ScrollToOptions): void;
> scroll(x: number, y: number): void;
> ```
>
> ...

Any idea to resolve this problem ?

Thanks